# how to keep a user selected image displayed when another action is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Ok, so complete noob here but basically here's my problem. I have a button which when clicked opens the photo library, after the user selects a photo it is displayed in a UIImageView.

```
//select photo

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}

//delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NO];
    // Handle a movie capture
        if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, self, nil, nil);
        }
    }
}

//photo
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
}



- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

 }
```

I also then have a button that opens the photo library and pic a video or take a video, this is then displayed.However if an image is picked and then the other button is clicked, once the video is chosen and the original view controller is displayed the UIImage is now blank.However what is confusing me is that this doesn't happen if the video is selected first, thanks for any help you can give and just ask if you need the code used for selecting the video, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delegate method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` is probably called once when you choose a photo and once when you choose a video. When you choose a photo, `info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]` contains the photo you choose but when you pick a video, it's probably `nil`. You should check in this method if you're dealling with a video or a photo and call this piece of code:

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
```

only if you're dealing with a photo (otherwise `self.imageView.image` would be set to `nil`)

EDIT: solution

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIIMagePickerController *)controller   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    if ([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] == kUTTypeImage) {
       //photo related code

    } else {
       //video related code

    }
}
```

Check the [doc for what's get returned in the info dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys). Hope you get it

Comment: thanks,i understand what you mean but am unsure of how to implement it could you give me some pointers?

Comment: ok edited my answer, check it out and let me know how it goes

Comment: That was great thanks works perfectly, obvious now that i think about it.